# Order of array after async activity

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mean-stack

I have the following piece of code that hits an API to upload an array of images and return their links in an array; however, the order in which the images are uploaded is not honored.

```
if (req.files) {

  var uploadedImages = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
    imgur.uploadFile(req.files[i].path)
      .then(function (json) {
        uploadedImages.push(json.data.link);
        if (uploadedImages.length === req.files.length) {
          console.log(uploadedImages);
          //Further processing
        }
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Imgur API Error!");
        console.log(err.message);
        res.redirect('/participants?err=' + encodeURIComponent('An unknown error occured. Please try again.'));
      });
  }
```

So for example, if I upload 1.jpg, 2.jpg, and 3.jpg, the array holding the respective links for these images is not necessarily in the same order. What is the best way to ensure that the order is not compromised during this async activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` to convert an array of promises into a promise of an array:

```
var uploads = req.files.map(function (file) {
  return imgur.uploadFile(file.path)
    .then(function (json) {
      return json.data.link;
    });
});

Promise.all(uploads)
  .then(function (uploadedImages) {
    console.log(uploadedImages);
    // Further processing
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Imgur API Error!");
    console.log(err.message);
    res.redirect('/participants?err=' + encodeURIComponent('An unknown error occured. Please try again.'));
  });
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Could you perhaps explain the logic behind `Promise.all()`?

Comment: @Rafay: A promise represents a value that you'll get at some point in the future. `Promise.all` waits for all of the promises you pass it to resolve to their values, then resolves to the values it collected as another array.

Comment: @Rafay: e.g. `all([resolve(1), resolve(2), resolve[3])` is `resolve([1, 2, 3])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function uploader(file) { 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       //do upload here and resolve path
       resolve('PATH AFTER UPLOAD')
    }); 
}

if(req.files) {
    tasks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
         tasks.push(uploader(req.files[i].path)) 
    }
    Promise.all(tasks)
    .then(uploadedImagesPath => { 
        console.log(uploadedImagesPath );
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err)//any error 
    });
}
```

Promise.all  that resolves when all of the promises in the given iterable have resolved, or rejects if any of the promises rejects.

If any of the passed in promises rejects, all Promise immediately rejects with the value of the promise that rejected, discarding all the other promises whether or not they have resolved. If an empty array is passed, then this method resolves immediately.